# Is it possible to use one constructor for everything in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I am a beginner at C++. I want to create a simple class that holds sum of numbers. Do I have to use 4 different constructors for all cases, or can I implement every possibility in one class?

```
class A {
private:
    int total;
    int x, y, z;

public:
    A() {
        total = 0;
    }
    A(int x) {
        this->x = x;
        total = x;
    }
    A(int x, int y) {
        total = x + y;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    A(int x, int y, int z) {
        total = x + y + z;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Comment: Do `A(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0) { total=x+y+z; this->x=x; this->y=y; this->z=z; }` meet your requirement? (It will initialize variables that are not explicitly specified while original code won't)

Comment: What you do is bad because some members may be left uninitialized. The correct way here is to default initialize y and z to 0 when then are not passed in constructor.

Comment: Incidentally, if you do use all three constructors, all of them need to initialise all member variables.   If they don't, in the case here, some `int` members may be uninitialised and accessing their values then gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Or. in the declaration you write `int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;` in modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is constructor delegation. Since C++11 you can call other constructors from a constructor of the same class. With that you can avoid writing duplicate code or an extra initialization method.

```
class A
{
private:

    int total = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

public:

    A(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->total += x;
    }
    A(int x, int y) : A(x)
    {           
        this->y = y;
        this->total += y;
    }
    A(int x, int y, int z) : A(x, y)
    {
        this->z = z;
        this->total += z;           
    }
};
```

However for your specific example it's probably best to just use default parameters instead of multiple constructors:

```
class B
{
private:

    int total = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

public:

    B(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {
        this->total = x + y + z;
    }
};
```

Comment: you should use member initializer list

Comment: Thank you so much.If i had a char* that keeps string could i use it as char* a="None";

Comment: @ bolov i didn't want to change too much from his original code to not confuse him. Of course you are right that initializers are better. It also only works for B and not for A. delegating constructors can't have other initializers. Should i edit my answer?

Comment: @Eric yes, you should.